# getX flutter package use default theme style instead of my custom theme

Tags: flutter, themes, flutter-getx

Why when I switch page using Get(()=> Page2 of getX package, the app go back to default theme colors?
I have a custom theme with yellow color, but then it goes back to the flutter blue default color.
Am I  missing something?

**my code**

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Profile'),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.edit_note_outlined), onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            /*isVisible= !isVisible;
            isReadOnly = !isReadOnly;*/
          });
          Get.to(
              AddNewProduct(),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              transition: Transition.fade
          );
      },
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

**my main**

```
   Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
      home: const MyApp(),)
  );
}
```

**my custom theme**

```
@override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       title: 'Flutter app',
       theme: ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
         buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(
           textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
           ),
         )
       ),
       home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home'),
     );
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: code you use for switching the theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are using two app widgets:

- **GetMaterialApp** in root
- **MaterialApp** in MyApp

But you have to use only GetMaterialApp.

In your `main` function remove `GetMaterialApp`

```
runApp(const MyApp(),);
```

In your MyApp widget replace `MaterialApp` with `GetMaterialApp`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter app',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
          buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
            ),
          )
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
```

**ANSWER THAT DEPENDS ON CONTEXT**

Let's look on structure of your widget tree

```
GetMaterialApp
  Builder (context1)
    MaterialApp <-- here you are setup your theme
     Scaffold
        AppBar
           Navigator.of(context1).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AddNewProduct()));
        body: ...
```

As you can see when you are navigating to the AddNewProduct screen you request context from the Builder widget where your theme is not set up and you launch a new screen with the default theme

To solve this you have two options:

- wrap Scaffold with another Builder widget
- move everything that is related to body property to a separate widget

I prefer the second option:

```
runApp(GetMaterialApp(home: Builder(builder: (context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter app',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
          buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
          )),
      home: const HomeWidget(),
    );
  })));
```

And your HomeWidget:

```
class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Profile'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit_note_outlined),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AddNewProduct()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: ... your content here...
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really get it. Your code looks different... however i tried to implement your solution, without success.

Comment: I updated unswer

Comment: ok thanks a lot. now it's clear and works.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two `MaterialApp` classes. The 'normal' one and the `GetMaterialApp`. You should get rid of the normal one, and move all parameters to the `GetMaterialApp`. `GetMaterialApp` replaces `MaterialApp`. So like

```
   Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
       title: 'Flutter app',
       theme: ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
         buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(
           textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
           ),
         )
       ),
       home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home'),  );
}
```

You probably don't need your `MyApp` class anymore. Or alternatively replace the `MaterialApp` in `MyApp` with `GetMaterialApp` and remove it from main like

```
  runApp(const MyApp());
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
      home: const MyApp(),)
  );
}
```

to

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
theme: ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
         buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(
           textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
           ),
         )
       ),
      home: const MyApp(),)
  );
}
```

Do not use `*GetMaterialApp(*` in build use `Scaffold`

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 material classes.

-> MaterialApp

-> GetMaterialApp

Remove **GetMaterialApp** from main class

```
runApp(const MyApp(),);
```

And replace **MaterialApp** to **GetMaterialApp** in MyApp widget

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter app',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
          buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
            ),
          )
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
```